# Required to withdraw due to student "not benefitting from further study" - is that ever used?

Tags: withdraw

At an institution in my country, the undergraduate calendar has the following language:

"Any student may be required to withdraw at any time if, in the
opinion of the Faculty Council he is unlikely to profit from further study. " (this quote is from a very old version of the calendar, hence the gender-specific language, but the modern version has nearly identical language)

This is in addition to the other withdrawal rules (like failing to maintain a given average).  It appears that this rule is basically at the discretion of the faculty.  I'm certain there are huge documentation requirements to make it enforceable without appeal, but I was wondering:

1. Is this a common clause at other institutions?
2. What does it mean to be "...unlikely to profit from further study"?  What are some examples?
3. Has anyone ever heard of it happening anywhere?

Comment: I wonder if it is an attempt to push out the "forever student" who is just too comfortable. There may also be an issue of needing to balance the individual's desires to stay with society's need to spread the value of education more widely - especially if funding is public.

Comment: @Buffy I'm not sure.  I asked around and everyone came up with a different answer, but no one seemed to know that the rule existed...

Comment: Sounds like it's about making adequate progress toward a degree, whatever the reason. The phrasing gives a lot of leeway. Here's an example: http://www.ucalendar.uwaterloo.ca/9596/MATH/mathpol.html